# Internet Explorer cache location

Tags: internet-explorer, caching

Where is cache for IE for current user located?

Comment: Why was this closevoted?

Comment: This question should go to SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default, the locations of Temporary Internet Files (for Internet Explorer) are:

**Windows 95, Windows 98, and Windows ME**

```
c:\WINDOWS\Temporary Internet Files
```

**Windows 2000 and Windows XP**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\\[User]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files
```

**Windows Vista and Windows 7**

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low
```

**Windows 8**

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
```

**Windows 10**

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
```

**Cache for Microsoft Edge**

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache
```

Some information came from [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/temporary-internet-files-folder-location).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to find the folder in a platform independent way, you should query the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Cache
```

Answer (score 10):

The location of the `Temporary Internet Files` folder depends on your version of Windows and whether or not you are using user profiles.

- If you have **Windows Vista**, then temporary Internet files are in these locations (note that on your PC they can be on some drive other than C):

  > C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\
  >   C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\

  Note that you will have to change the settings of Windows Explorer to show all kinds of files (including the protected system files) in order to access these folders.
- If you have **Windows XP** or **Windows 2000**, then temporary Internet files are in this location (note that on your PC they can be on some drive other than C):

  > C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\

  If you have only one user account, then replace [username] with Administrator to get the path of the `Temporary Internet Files` folder.
- If you have **Windows Me**, **Windows 98**, **Windows NT** or **Windows 95**, then `index.dat` files are in these locations:

  > C:\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\
  >   C:\Windows\Profiles[username]\Temporary Internet Files\

  Note that on your computer, the Windows directory may not be `C:\Windows` but some other directory. If you don't have a `Profiles` directory in your `Windows` directory, don't worry — this just means that you are not using user profiles.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer for XP, but for latter:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5` - these are cache locations. Other mentioned `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files` but this not a cache in this directory there are just a reflection of files that are stored somewhere else.

But you can enum `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files` and get all files you need, but you should be frustrated that file walker do not detect everything that explorer shows.

Also if you use links I gave you may need [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from WinAPI.

Comment: +1 "just a reflection of files that are stored somewhere else." - poetic and accurate. But, sadly the links here are not accurate for Windows 10. Does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dot.Net then the code you need is

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)

Click my name if you want the code to delete these files plus FireFox temp files and Flash shared object/Flash Cookies

Answer (score 1):

In windows serven and 8 and later in this location can find IE Cache

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache

Answer (score 0):

If it's been moved you can also (in IE 11, and I'm pretty sure this translates back to at least 10):

- Tools - Internet Options
- Under Browsing history click Settings
- Under Current location it shows the directory name

Note: The View files button will open a Windows Explorer window there.

For example, mine shows C:\BrowserCache\IE\Temporary Internet Files

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Windows API?

Just use [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE flag or [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with FOLDERID_InternetCache flag to get the exact location. This way you don't have to worry about the OS. The former function works in Windows XP. The latter one works in Windows Vista+.