# So where are the downloaded CSS files stored?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I view a web page via IE and check the source code. In it, I find this tag:`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forumdata/cache/style_12_common.css?Ccx" />`. I suppose this means the web page comes with a CSS sheet and it's downloaded onto my computer under some temp folder? But I looked at the Temporary Internet Files folder, it was not there. So my question is where are the css files normally stored?

Comment: I'm not sure about IE offhand (that's why this is a comment and not an answer), but in Firefox, you can enter "about:cache" in the address bar to view cache entries from various cache devices. For example, click on one of the "List Cache Entries" links and search the page for the filename that you're looking for. Then click on the "key" link to view the cache entry. Click the key again to view the actual cached file.

Comment: Apparently this utility is the easiest way to view the IE cache: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html

Answer (score 1):

**Edit to add:** In an act of recursive (circular?) Googling, it appears that SO has another question which contains the answer to "[where is the IE cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854412/internet-explorer-cache-location)"

I'm not sure about IE, but Firefox has a Cache folder under your profile directory. For my Linux box, it's `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/Cache/`. The folder looks like this (this is a list of files within the directory, in case you're not familiar with Unix/Linux):

```
[20:36:44] ~/.mozilla/firefox/dk6fwbbj.default/Cache $ ls
00C56123d01  334039C7d01  700B13E5d01  92393F82d01  B69F8DE4d01  E1F99924d01
012339DDd01  3A9A68BCd01  71FF4ED1d01  9243F45Ed01  BA493504d01  E4E00324d01
037348D3d01  3C4AC614d01  72C8CEC0d01  92B52013d01  BB86F350d01  E859A0FCd01
03853A65d01  3C80A952d01  72D4BE1Ad01  940EB7F7d01  BC018BB6d01  E870B684d01
077DC091d01  3D836843d01  72F96B17d01  941D6849d01  BC9A173Bd01  EDB6437Ed01
07FD89F5d01  3FCEE28Fd01  7539C750d01  95271C82d01  C279B0F8d01  EE63135Fd01
0A5F348Ed01  3FF14615d01  75F022C4d01  95C75CD0d01  C3794520d01  EEE47171d01
0AD8884Dd01  4043D770d01  788F4621d01  96B132EBd01  C4F55DF1d01  EF242AEBd01
0E109194d01  42723FEBd01  79221C58d01  984C14FDd01  C57415D3d01  EF8B0F23d01
12342345d01  442D11BFd01  79475512d01  9988F946d01  C5F20BB5d01  F08CF2B7d01
19CACB1Bd01  48251E09d01  79ED3E52d01  9A3A0149d01  C6849F0Ed01  F092E396d01
1B36C300d01  487A6337d01  7A96B218d01  9BB04B2Fd01  _CACHE_001_  F412BCA2d01
20700CB5d01  4945A4A0d01  7BF44070d01  9E204875d01  _CACHE_002_  F7244486d01
22586D64d01  4BB37585d01  7D6A17E7d01  9F960283d01  _CACHE_003_  F8267AFAd01
231BBB5Bd01  51C94367d01  7FC74BB9d01  A2875302d01  _CACHE_MAP_  FC47F8FFd01
2A58D97Cd01  52D4E476d01  80EBF2CDd01  A4D4D28Ad01  CE6E2E3Ad01  FD5C4583d01
2C21BE1Cd01  5AD48B1Cd01  82B87282d01  A5F56480d01  CEEF1936d01  FD5D91ABd01
2D19219Ed01  5B3C0D0Ad01  84BFAD4Fd01  A6541AAEd01  D2333F52d01  FF10CACDd01
2F4138C8d01  5E07A792d01  84D2DAF9d01  AA7E06A9d01  D25B5CDDd01
2F6C237Fd01  669EA2A9d01  857A2691d01  B0D4AE97d01  D6E28915d01
3058F347d01  68E61CCCd01  88D1BD18d01  B49E3998d01  D7DB1F90d01
30B9D5CCd01  6AC45753d01  8A088207d01  B4F10D7Ed01  DB526AF3d01
31BD736Bd01  6DD04606d01  8D9AA2B1d01  B5F58FDFd01  E19B4778d01
[20:37:41] ~/.mozilla/firefox/dk6fwbbj.default/Cache $
```

and a quick `grep` of these files (which are not named in a way that is helpful to humans) shows that there is CSS code in some of them:

```
[20:37:50] ~/.mozilla/firefox/dk6fwbbj.default/Cache $ grep 'color:' *
B49E3998d01:    .ctl00_TreeView1_2 { color:White; }
B49E3998d01:    .ctl00_TreeView1_3 { background-color:#3366FF;width:180px; }
Binary file _CACHE_001_ matches
Binary file _CACHE_002_ matches
Binary file _CACHE_003_ matches
[20:38:57] ~/.mozilla/firefox/dk6fwbbj.default/Cache $
```

I'd imagine IE probably does something similar, if you're interested in that browser. Try Googling for it, perhaps, but I don't use IE.