# Where to store a temporary copy of a network file in Windows - INetCache?

Tags: windows, temporary-files

I would like to create a temporary copy of a network file while actively working on it in our application which is a Windows desktop application.  I am concerned about folder-redirection and potentially Citrix as some of our users employ these.

After some analysis of Microsoft Word, I have discovered that it writes its local cache of a network file into %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.MSO (in Windows 10).

I have read this former post [Internet Explorer Cache Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854412/internet-explorer-cache-location/854425#854425) that says to check the registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Cache
to be sure of where temporary internet files are stored on the local machine.

I would anticipate creating a subfolder of the "temporary internet files" folder named essentially Content.*MyApplicationName*, as Microsoft appears to do.

So my question is whether this is indeed the best place to store a local cache of a network file while working on it, allowing for the possibility that folder-redirection could have been employed on the machine.

Comment: I would forget about INetCache, its for use by specific applications and (afaik) is not a recommended storage path for anything else to use.  Hard to see any issues using the temporary path the system provides via GetTempPath().

Comment: Thank you @AlexK.- yes, that was my first thought, until I discovered that Microsoft didn't use it.  You could well be right though.

Comment: I have discovered that there is an API for accessing the temporary internet cache in Wininet.h.  I will investigate methods like CreateUrlCacheEntryW to see whether they might do what I want.

It also appears that INetCache uses an NTFS Junction to ensure that the files are stored on the local disk.